# How to smooth sequence by padding with linear interpolation

Tags: r, interpolation, smoothing

I have a data set that looks like this

```
Category<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
Sequence<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
Data<-c(2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,4)

DF<-data.frame(Category,Sequence,Data)
```

I'd like to smooth out the Data column (linear interpolation) by padding the Sequence column with additional numbers (keeping the Category constant). If I were to pad the sequence with only one number in between each value, the result would look like this:

```
NewCat<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
NewSeq<-c(1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5)
NewData<-c(2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5)
NewDF<-data.frame(NewCat,NewSeq,NewData)
```

I've written a for loop to do this (padding with 20 as opposed to one), but I'd like to use something more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you want in Base R, using the `approx` function. Change the value of `Interval` as required. It uses `tapply` to construct a new data frame for each value of `Category`, with a new sequence of `Sequence` and interpolated `Data`, then binds them together. Ignore the row names.

```
Interval <- 0.5
NewDF <- do.call(rbind,
      tapply(seq_along(DF$Sequence), DF$Category, function(x) {
           Seqvals <- seq(min(DF$Sequence[x]), max(DF$Sequence[x]), Interval)
           Intvals <- approx(DF$Sequence[x], DF$Data[x], Seqvals)$y
           return(data.frame(Category=DF$Category[min(x)],
                             Sequence=Seqvals,
                             Data=Intvals))}))
NewDF
    Category Sequence Data
1.1        1      1.0  2.0
1.2        1      1.5  2.5
1.3        1      2.0  3.0
1.4        1      2.5  3.5
1.5        1      3.0  4.0
1.6        1      3.5  4.5
1.7        1      4.0  5.0
1.8        1      4.5  5.5
1.9        1      5.0  6.0
2.1        2      1.0  4.0
2.2        2      1.5  4.5
2.3        2      2.0  5.0
2.4        2      2.5  5.5
2.5        2      3.0  6.0
2.6        2      3.5  6.5
2.7        2      4.0  7.0
2.8        2      4.5  6.5
2.9        2      5.0  6.0
3.1        3      1.0  5.0
3.2        3      1.5  4.5
3.3        3      2.0  4.0
3.4        3      2.5  3.5
3.5        3      3.0  3.0
3.6        3      3.5  2.5
3.7        3      4.0  2.0
3.8        3      4.5  3.0
3.9        3      5.0  4.0
```